Docusign add document
i need to add some document to be signed in addition to the main document. Would be like another page that needs to be signed too.. but when user sign the document the status change to close and i can´t edit to add the new page anymore Someone know is its possible to make this addendum in some contract that already been signed?
Trying to put someone who won´t sign the contract in the end of the workflow to always have the chance do edit the document and add new page to the customer sign again, but this way the contract gonna always be in the status waiting for  signature

Welcome! Please accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!

Once an envelope reaches a terminal state (completed (signed), voided, or another terminal state), that's it. No further changes can be made.
Workflow: you can make changes after the last signer has signed by adding a fake signer to stop the routing process of the envelope (remember to set signer order).
Once the envelope reaches that "signer," your software can change the envelope. Eventually, your software should delete the fake signer to enable the envelope to complete
The eSignature API also has a workflow object, but it only enables you to pause the envelope routing before a recipient. If your signer is the last recipient, it won't meet your needs. But if, for example, your last recipient is a cc recipient, check out the API's workflow option.

Thank you Larry,
After the first version of the contract is signed, I gonna download the document and add to the another one
